# SCCM Required SQL Server Collation already set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sccm, windows-server-2016

I have two questions.

1. I am installing SCCM 2016 on a Windows Server 2016, but I am stuck at the prerequisite screen. It keeps asking me to change the Required SQL Server Collation to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_A`S. But when I look on the SQL Server it is already on that collation.
2. My SCCM Server reports the above problem. Why isn't my SQL Server reporting that problem?

Thanks in advance for helping me!

---

Screenshot with the error:
[image: Screenshot with the error]

Current SQL-collation
[image: Current SQL-collation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SqlACID mentioned, you need to reinstall SQL with  "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"[image]

**SQL Server security mode**

On the SQL Server, Right click SQL instance go to properties and then Security. Make sure you have selected Windows Authentication Mode only, and run check to verify warning is gone.

[image]

**Configuration for SQL Server memory usage**

On properties of SQL server, under Memory set minimum and maximum memory to 8192.

[image]

**SQL Server process memory allocation**

Configuration Manager requires SQL Server to reserve a minimum of 8 gigabytes (GB) of memory for the central administration site and primary site and a minimum of 4 gigabytes (GB) for the secondary site. This memory is reserved by using the Minimum server memory setting under Server Memory Options and is configured by using SQL Server Management Studio. For more information about how to set a fixed amount of memory, see [Here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=233759).

Comment: SQL was allocated 2147483647MB of RAM :o

Answer (score 1):

Check the properties on the existing database (right click the database, Properties, Options), each database has it's own setting; possibly the database was created on a different server?

Comment: The databaseserver is located on SQLMA. I have entered in the setup. And still he looks on sccmma

Comment: The error states it wants "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS", you have "Latin1_General_CI_AS", which is not quite the same thing..close but not quite (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/rocks/2012/01/09/revised-difference-between-collation-sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as-and-latin1_general_ci_as/)  . The SQL Server collation setting can only be set at install time last I knew.